# Separating posts in Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

lately, I've been trying to code my own Tumblr blog theme. Now, I have abit of knowledge in HTML, and am quit experienced in CSS. However, I cannot seem to separate the posts in the theme. The code I am using is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="color:Background" content="#000000">
 <meta name="font:Body" content="Georgia" />
 <meta name="image:Background" content="http://i41.tinypic.com/wvztsk.png" />
 <meta name="color:Primary Colour" content="#03999b" />
 <meta name="color:Secondary Colour" content="#4cc3c5" />
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>{Title}{block:PostSummary}, {PostSummary}{/block:PostSummary}</title>
 {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />

<style type="text/css">

/* Header */
    .headerstuff {
    background-color: black;
    color: silver;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: -10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: -2px;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
}

body {
    background-color:{color:Background};
    font-family:{font:Body};
}

.links {
    color: red;
    text-align: left;
}    

#content {
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.contentcontainer {
    width:1480px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#contentcontainer #content {
      background-color: white;
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto 20px;
      padding:10px;
}

#content .title {
    font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
    font-size:30px;
    color: silver;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', cursive;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="headerstuff">"Welcome to Neverland!"</div>
</header>
<div class="contentcontainer">
<div id ="content">{block:Posts}

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<div class="text">{Body}</div>
{/block:Text}





{/block:Posts}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I have only coded the text side of things, but as you can see in the screenshot provided, I cannot seem to separate  the two text's in two seperate boxes. Anybody help?
[image: See that they are not separated?]

Comment: You mean you want more space between posts? Or do you want a line between the posts?

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside `{block:Posts}` and `{/block:Posts}` gets rendered for each post.

So to keep each post in a separate `DIV` your code should be something like;

```
<body>

<header>
<div class="headerstuff">"Welcome to Neverland!"</div>
</header>

<div class="contentcontainer">

{block:Posts}

<div class="content">

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<div class="text">{Body}</div>
{/block:Text}

</div>

{/block:Posts}

</div>

</body>
```

Then use CSS `margin` for `.content` to have some space in between each post.

Also remember to change `#content` to `.content` in you CSS.

See the [documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) for more help. There is also HTML markup for a sample theme, complete with all type of post Tumblr currently supports (except `Answer` post).